# PHP MySQLi Prepared Statement Transaction Insert ID

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, prepared-statement

So I'm looking into create a MySQLi Transaction with prepared statements in PHP. I seem to have the idea all fine, however I have an issue. My statements rely on each other. For example:

Email address entered into email table.
User entered into user table with Email Address ID as a foreign key

See code below, which shows two prepared statements, the second relying on the first for the e-mail ID:

```
//$email_sql
                if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($email_sql))) throw new \Exception("[mysqli] Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
                if(!($stmt->bind_param('s', $email)) throw new \Exception("[mysqli] Bind Params failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
                //$user_sql
                if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($user_sql))) throw new \Exception("[mysqli] Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
                if(!($stmt->bind_param('i', $SHOULD_BE_EMAIL_ID)) throw new \Exception("[mysqli] Bind Params failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);
```

You can see where I have put '$SHOULD_BE_EMAIL_ID', there is where the issue lies. As I can see, there's no way for me to get this value as the first query hasn't yet been executed at this point in the code. Is there a way for me to get round this? I.e. is there any functions that will allow me to get the email ID there. As far as I can see, I have not been able to find one.

The only way I can think of a solution at the moment, is changing the logic of my code, so it does utilise transactions, which if I can avoid, I will.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: MySQLi lets you get the AUTOINC ID of the last inserted element: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score -1):

These two statements

> I'm looking into create a MySQLi Transaction (1)
>   I will avoid transactions if I can (2)

Looks mutual exclusive to me.

So, your answer is very simple and can be based on two logical conclusions:

- you cannot have a transaction without having a transaction
- besides, you cannot execute a query without executing a query.

So, just start using transactions if you need them.

That's all.

Answer (score -1):

For Fetching the last inserted ID using PDO::lastInsertId(). And separate the insertion into two statements [made 1st statement insert and another updation].